# How to add a doc to a folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I am generating a document using Google App Script (specifically a document, not a spreadsheet) and I need to be able to add it to a folder I have called "Test Documents".

I have tried

```
doc.addToFolder("Test Documents");
```

However, in debug mode I get the error that the method addToFolder is not found. I'm trying to use this functionality: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#addToFolder

Could someone give me an example of how I might do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method addToFolder is part of DocsList service, here is an example :

```
  var Doc = DocsList.getFileById('1INkRIviwdjMC-PVT9io5LpiiLW8VwwIfgbq2E4xvKEo');
  var gas = DocsList.getFolderById('0B3qSFd3iikE3NWY0dndsMTFZMDQ')
  Doc.addToFolder(gas)
```

Comment: Worked great. I ended up using var document = DocsList.getFileById(doc.getId()); for anyone searching for this in the future.